# difference between a 5 v 1a and 5v 0.65a hd

Tags: hard-drive

What's the difference in the ampere of  a 5v. 1A laptop hard disk and 5VDC 0.65A 12VDC :0.50 A PC hard disk for my laptop.

Comment: The difference is 0.35A. What more do you want?

Comment: do you know what you actually asked? ... i suspect that you are thinking that ampere is a measurement of power

Comment: Probably a different motor...

Comment: Please be more specific on what you mean by "what's the difference". It may help if you describe your situation and the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The small laptop drive consumes 5 watts of power (5V*1A).

The larger desktop drive consumes 9.25 watts of power (5V*0.65A + 12V*0.5A).

The desktop drive probably has a larger motor to spin the larger platters and a larger servo to move the heads over a longer distance. Desktop drive traditionally use 12 volt for the motor fo efficiency. However, laptops generally do not provide 12 volts for the hard drives so their smaller motors run off of the 5 volts needed by the rest of the drive.

Comment: its going to damage my laptop or driver if I use the desktop drive on my laptop_

Comment: @noob I assume that’s a question. (It’d help if you used punctuation such as a question mark.) As I noted, your laptop is unlikely to provide 12 volts on the HDD connector. If it did, it probably wouldn’t provide enough current for a desktop drive. However, there’s no reason you cannot use an external power supply (connected to the SATA power connector of the drive).

Comment: But the question remain if its going to damage my motherboard if i use it ?

Comment: @noob Assuming you properly power the hard drive, there is no reason it would damage anything